# Date sort(ascending-descending) in data Table according to month and day but not work for year.So I want solution for that in javaScript

Tags: html, knockout.js, durandal

Date sort(ascending-descending) in data Table according to month and day but it's not working for a year. So I want solution for that in javaScript.

Here I attach image:

[image]

Comment: Consider making code snipped ([<>] button on question edit panel) to provide working demo of your issue for people who may help you with it. Otherwise it is a bit difficult to analyze the bunch of abstract code trying to find a black cat in the dark room which may not even be there.

Comment: Date sorting apply in format DD-MM-YYYY. when system date format change its not workin.So I need date sorting solution for all date format.